# boost locale - basic usage to convert numbers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, localization, boost-locale

Well this is "strange" but I can't seem to convert numeric values to strings using boost::locale (under microsoft visual studio 2010) and boost lexical cast.

```
int main() {

    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale::global(std::locale(gen("de_DE")));
    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<double>("1,253") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the german locale the "," sign should be used as a decimal identifier. So above should read "1.253". However it doesn't work (lexical_cast gives an exception) - Using `std::locale::global(std::locale("German_Germany.1252"));` does work - however I wish to use a portable system and not "limit" myself to microsoft's naming/codepages.

How would I use boost::locale, or use a more portable localization than std::locale?